# Algebras of objects and algebras of terms

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying to follow W. Richard Stark's *LISP, Lore, and Logic*, specifically the Chapter 6 "Interpreters: From Algebra to LISP". He talks very general and theoretical about "algebras":

> Algebras are discrete mathematical systems which formalize the
>   behavior of functions and relations over a domain. In the abstract,
>   algebras are of the form

$$
    (domain, c_1,c_2,...f_1,f_2,...,r_1,r_2...)
$$

> where the $c$'s are constants, the $f$'s are functions, and the $r$'s
>   are relations. . . .

Does anybody know of a good text or on-line source that talks about algebras in such theoretical language? I've gotten lost with Stark's cursory treatment.

Comment: Given that he also includes relations, what he calls "algebras" are what everyone else calls "models". So, check out any of several good books and online resources about Model Theory.

Comment: @BrianO, yep, or "structures", or "first-order structures", or "mathematical structures," or "monosorted structures of finite airity." Logic has a lot of terminology :)

Comment: Can anyone suggest a good beginner's explanation, book or otherwise?

Comment: True. Without relations, "algebras" is his sense are studied in "universal algebra", so also take a look at that. "Term algebras" would be examples of these. Note that there is also a much narrower definition of "algebra", but he doesn't mean those.

Comment: Try the wikipedia articles on these two topics, for starters. There are plenty of "beginner's books" in the sense that they don't assume you've encountered their subject before -- they're first courses, intros to -- but they aren't necessarily "elementary" in terms of required mathematical maturity.

Comment: Wikipedia links: [Universal algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra) and [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory). Both articles contain good, even very good bibliographies; the latter also has links to several online free texts.